# Genymotion centos virtual device got no IP adress

Tags: centos, virtualbox, genymotion, vnc-viewer

I'm using

- virtualbox 5.2
- centos 8
- genymotion 2.12

In vnc viewer

I'm getting this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXkIR.png)

I tried almost evey solution i found in stackoverflow and askubuntu, still not resolved

Anyone can figure it out will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion 2.12 is depreciated and it probably does not work well with VirtualBox 5.2.
You should upgrade to Genymotion 3.0.4 or wait a little bit and go for 3.1.